# Ember centralised error handling within an Action

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Inside an Ember `controller` I have a number of `actions` which perform data events (create update and delete) on the store.

Each of these requests has the same error handling logic which is repeated many times. If there a way of centralising this error logic?

1. Given this logic will be used by many routes, what would be the best location in Ember for it to live?
2. How can the context be preserved so `this` is still available to send toast type of messages to the DOM ?

Here is an example of what I have now

```
createEntryRecord() {
  // This action is a 'create' button on a modal
  set(this, 'isLoadingModal', true);  // shows loading spinner
  let dbid = this.get('dbidModal');
  let type = this.get('entryModalType');

  this.get('store').createRecord('my-store', {
    type,
    dbid
  })
  .save()
  .then((record) => {
    get(this, 'flashMessages').success(`Created`);  // Toast message
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    // Begin of the error handling logic
    let errors = get(e, 'errors');
    if (errors.length) {
      errors.forEach(err => {
        let field = err.source.pointer.split("/").pop();
        get(this, 'flashMessages').danger(`${field}: ${err.detail}`);
      });
    } else {
      let message = get(e, 'message');
      get(this, 'flashMessages').danger(`${message}`);
    }
  })
  .finally(() => {
    set(this, 'isLoadingModal', false);  // stop the loading spinner
    set(this, 'isEntryModalShown', false);
  });
},
```

Comment: how about making an error service that you can inject to where ever you want and re-use as needed?

Comment: @alptugd That sounds like a good approach. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a solution that utilises Ember's Object Model [Mixins](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.16/classes/Mixin).
First you create a common Mixin for all your models:

```
// app/mixins/flashing-model.js
import Mixin from '@ember/object/mixin';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Mixin.create({
    flashMessages: service(), // can be accessed via this.get('flashMessages')
    save(...args) {
        const superSavePromise = this._super(...args);
        superSavePromise.then(() => {
            // your positive logic
        }).catch(e => {
            // your negative logic
        });
        return superSavePromise;
    }
});
```

Then you include it in each of the models. For example:

```
// app/models/some-model.js
import FlashingModel from '{your-app-name}/mixins/flashing-model';
import DS from 'ember-data'
export default DS.Model.extend(FlashingModel, {
    // ...
});
```

After that you can edit your controller:

```
this.get('store').createRecord('my-store', {
    type,
    dbid
})
.save()
.finally(() => {
    // ...
});
```

So regarding your questions:
 1. Ember Mixins (under `app/mixins` directory) can be a good place to host common logic.
 2. When implementing the above solution you don't really need to preserve the controller's `this` context, since the [flashMessages service](https://github.com/poteto/ember-cli-flash#usage) is injected to each model. Hence, you can access the service within the `save` method's context, which is the `this` of model.

Comment: This is great!!  Just changed the function name from `save` so if I even need to bypass this logic save still works as expected.